# How can I get my JavaScript delete function to fire more than once?

Tags: javascript

I'm building a todo app and I use a function to create a list item entered by the user.

There is an event listener added to the output section to listen for a delete button click for each item displayed. My problem is that the delete button is only working for one item and then it stops working.

In the console, it appears that the function is actually called every time I press the button, but the functionality only works for one click. Do I need to add all the list items into an array perhaps?

```js
const todo = document.getElementById('todo');
const enter = document.getElementById('enter');
const output = document.getElementById('output');
enter.addEventListener('click', () => {
  listItem(todo);
});
let createListItem;
var deleteBtn;
let checkBtn;

function listItem(todo) {
  createListItem = document.createElement('li');
  createListItem.innerText = todo.value;
  todo.value = '';

  output.appendChild(createListItem);

  checkBtn = document.createElement('button');
  deleteBtn = document.createElement('button');

  checkBtn.innerText = 'check';
  deleteBtn.innerText = 'delete';

  createListItem.append(checkBtn);
  createListItem.append(deleteBtn);

  checkBtn.classList.add('checkBtn');
  deleteBtn.classList.add('deleteBtn');

}
output.addEventListener('click', deleteFunc);

function deleteFunc() {
  console.log('function called');
  createListItem.remove();
}
```

```html
<section class="controls">
  <div>
    <label for="todo">Enter a to-do</label>
    <input type="text" name="todo" id="todo">
  </div>
  <span>
    <button id="enter" class = "enter"><i class="fas fa-paper-plane"></i></button>
  </span>
</section>
<section>
  <ul id="output" class="output">

  </ul>

</section>
```

Comment: Instead of creating the buttons each time, just have their container hidden at the start and show it when you need it.  `document.getElementById('someID').style.display= 'block';`

Comment: @DominiqueFortin The buttons are needed for each item added...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to delegate and use [relative addressing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) because your code only removes the LAST added LI

The variable `createListItem` pollutes the global scope. Add the keyword `var` or `let` in the listItem function too

```
function deleteFunc(e) {
  console.log('function called');
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (e.target.innerText==="delete") tgt.closest("li").remove()
}
```

Added benefit from this delegation is that adding the functionality to the "check" button is just

```
  if (e.target.innerText==="check") ...
```

I would recommend to use a class and testing

```
if (e.target.classList.contains("delete")
```

instead of the innerText  - especially if you want to change language of the button

```js
const todo = document.getElementById('todo');
const enter = document.getElementById('enter');
const output = document.getElementById('output');
enter.addEventListener('click', () => {
  listItem(todo);
});
let createListItem;
var deleteBtn;
let checkBtn;

function listItem(todo) {
  let createListItem = document.createElement('li'); // use let or var here
  createListItem.innerText = todo.value;
  todo.value = '';

  output.appendChild(createListItem);

  checkBtn = document.createElement('button');
  deleteBtn = document.createElement('button');

  checkBtn.innerText = 'check';
  deleteBtn.innerText = 'delete';

  createListItem.append(checkBtn);
  createListItem.append(deleteBtn);

  checkBtn.classList.add('checkBtn');
  deleteBtn.classList.add('deleteBtn');

}
output.addEventListener('click', deleteFunc);

function deleteFunc(e) {
  console.log('function called');
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (e.target.innerText==="delete") tgt.closest("li").remove()
}
```

```html
<section class="controls">
  <div>
    <label for="todo">Enter a to-do</label>
    <input type="text" name="todo" id="todo">
  </div>
  <span>
    <button id="enter" class = "enter"><i class="fas fa-paper-plane"></i></button>
  </span>
</section>
<section>
  <ul id="output" class="output">

  </ul>

</section>
```

Comment: Thanks so much, this answer works and explains it to me the clearest

Answer (score 0):

Your `createListItem` variable is a global that gets set to the most-recently appended item, so the delete function will always delete the most-recent item. Once an element `el` has already been removed from the DOM tree, `el.remove()` is a no-op, so it only works once.

To fix, you can either use event delegation as in [@mplungjan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63757247) or assign a unique id to each list item and pass that as a parameter to the function to determine what to delete.

Example of the second approach:

```html
<ul>
  <li id="item-0"></li>
  <li id="item-1"></li>
  <li id="item-2"></li>
</ul>
```

```js
const deleteById = id => document.querySelector(`#item-${id}`).remove()
```

Answer (score 0):

First though:

I think os because you are targeting the "ul" instead the "li" elements. Try adding the event listeners to each "li" element with a querySelectorAll() instead of targeting "output" directly.

Answer (score 0):

When you add another item, you call `listItem()` which sets a new value to `createListItem`. This means, when you call `deleteFunc()`, `createListItem.remove();` is only executed on the last element you have added. If this item was already removed, your out of luck as well.

```
function deleteFunc(e) {
  console.log('function called');
  const { target } = e; // get target
  target.closest("li").remove()
}
```

Remove the listener on `output`. (This line: `output.addEventListener('click', deleteFunc);`)

And add the listener to each `deleteBtn`:

```
checkBtn.classList.add('checkBtn');
deleteBtn.classList.add('deleteBtn');
deleteBtn.addEventListener('click', deleteFunc);
```

This might help you:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest

Comment: The first part  is the same answer I already gave except for the convoluted casting you use when getting the target - but the second part is NOT recommended and also not necessary - the delegation works just fine on its own. It is recommended to delegate from the closest static container.

Comment: Hey @mplungjan, you would not believe it, but I started working on the question before your answer was posted. After reading your answer I see you left the listener on the whole `ul` and try to figure out if the correct button was pressed by it's textContent, which is bad for several reasons. I also don't know what 'casting ' you are talking about, no casting is happening at all!

Comment: I did not suggest you copied my answer, just it was the same. Destructuring `{ target } = e` is the most complex way I have ever seen someone getting e.target from. And yes, my code is simple delegation and it works excellently, especially when only a few things can be clicked. To extend my code to handle the "check" click is a one liner and you would add another event handler to the DOM  - making two event handlers for every LI in the output

Comment: It's called destructuring and shipped in ES6 (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring).

Comment: I know, it is just immense overkill  and making it harder to read for an obvious noob when only needing ONE attribute

Answer (score -1):

Find the solution.

```js
const todo = document.getElementById('todo');
const enter = document.getElementById('enter');
const output = document.getElementById('output');
enter.addEventListener('click', () => {
  listItem(todo);
});
let createListItem;
var deleteBtn;
let checkBtn;
var index = 0;

function listItem(todo) {
  createListItem = document.createElement('li');
  createListItem.innerText = todo.value;
  createListItem.id= 'li' + index;
  todo.value = '';

  output.appendChild(createListItem);

  checkBtn = document.createElement('button');
  deleteBtn = document.createElement('button');

  checkBtn.innerText = 'check';
  deleteBtn.innerText = 'delete';
  deleteBtn.id = 'btn' + index;

  createListItem.append(checkBtn);
  createListItem.append(deleteBtn);

  checkBtn.classList.add('checkBtn');
  deleteBtn.classList.add('deleteBtn');
  deleteBtn.onclick = function() { deleteFunc(this); };
  index += 1;
}
//output.addEventListener('click', deleteFunc);

function deleteFunc(e) {

      var rowId    = e.id.replace('btn','');
         var row = document.getElementById('li'+rowId);
         console.log('function called' + rowId);
        //alert(rowId);
       if (row != null) {
            row.remove();
       }
  //console.log('function called');
  //createListItem.remove();
}
```

```html
<section class="controls">
  <div>
    <label for="todo">Enter a to-do</label>
    <input type="text" name="todo" id="todo">
  </div>
  <span>
    <button id="enter" class = "enter"><i class="fas fa-paper-plane"></i></button>
  </span>
</section>
<section>
  <ul id="output" class="output">

  </ul>

</section>
```